# SQL inner join with conditional selection

Tags: sql, case, inner-join

I am new in SQL. Lets say I have 2 tables one is `table_A` and the other one is `table_B`. And I want to create a view with two of them which is `view_1`.

table_A:

| id | foo |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | d |
| 2 | e |
| null | f |

table_B

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a |
| 2 | b |
| 3 | c |

and when I use this query :

```
SELECT DISTINCT table_A.id, table_B.name
FROM table_A 
INNER JOIN table_B ON table_B.id = table_A.id
```

the null value in `table_A` can't be seen in the `view_1` since it is not found in `table_B`. I want `view_1` to show also this null row like :

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a |
| 2 | b |
| null | no entry |

Should I create a 4. table? I couldn't find a way.

Comment: Have you tried with `left join` instead of `inner join`?

Comment: Yes it might work :) I will try this. And the last thing is change the name I think I can do this. Sorry for easy question.

Comment: On a side note: Why `DISTINCT`?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? You SQL requests should be tagged with your DBMS, so you only get answers that work for you.

Comment: Explain "no entry".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this Query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.id,(CASE When b.name IS NULL OR b.name = '' Then 'No Entry' else b.name end) name FROM table_A a  
LEFT JOIN table_B b on a.id = b.id
```

[image: Try This]

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for an outer join. Thus you keep all table_A rows and join table_B rows where they exist. If no match exists, the table_B columns in the joined row are NULL.

You replace NULLs with a value with `COALESCE`.

```
SELECT a.id, COALESCE(b.name, 'no entry') AS name
FROM table_a a
LEFT OUTER JOIN table_b b ON b.id = a.id
ORDER BY a.id NULLS LAST;
```

You haven't tagged your request with your DBMS. Not all DBMS support the `NULLS LAST` clause.

Please note that there is no `DISTINCT` in my query. It is not needed. And every time you think you must use `DISTINCT`, think twice. `SELECT DISTINCT` is very seldom needed. Most often it is used, because the query is kind of flawed and causes the undesired duplicates itself.